# Is there a way to route to multiple files in my views in Ruby on Rails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

I am making a website dedicated to flash and unity games to learn Ruby on Rails hands on and I wanted to know if there was a way to route to all the documents in a folder without entering them in the routes file one by one. I am not sure if I am just being blind, but I have been looking everywhere for an answer.

For example i have to enter:
Get 'game1', to: "games#game1"
In the routes file for an individual game, but I want to be able to add a entire library without having to enter them in one by one.

Comment: I highly recommend reading this: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resource-routing-the-rails-default
In your case, the resources would be the games.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

correct me if i'm wrong, but you have several files (games) into the games view folder and you want to route through a single action?

so, basically, in your routes.rb would have:

```
get "games/:game_number" => "games#show"
```

and then, on your games_controller.rb

```
def show
  # ...
  render "games/#{params[:game_number]}"
end
```

so, in this case, if you hit /games/first, it would render the view games/first.html.erb

this is not a good practice since the are several pitfalls through out, but, having that in mind, this should work if i got the right scenario :)

Comment: Sorry, this is old and I have the project backed up. This did work out thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is what variable segments are for. You should be using something like

```
get "games/:id" => "games#show"
```

and looking up the game by `params[:id]`.